# 1) State 2) Action and then 3) Reward diagram: Which ML approach to use?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

[image]

It is looks like a reinforcement learning diagram however it's slightly different. I'll explain the numbers.

- 1) The environment *first* gives the agent a *state*
- 2) The agent does it's magic and then returns an *action*
- 3) The environment decides if this action is to be *rewarded* or *punished* for that action which depended on the state first sent

Is there a ML approach that satisfys this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just formulate this as some loss over $\hat{y} = f(\mathbf{X})$ where $\mathbf{X}$ is the state (input vector), $\hat{y}$ is the action (prediction) and the loss is how you decide to reward/punish?

If you can indeed formulate it like this, you basically want to identify $f$, which sounds like standard regression (continuous $\hat{y}$) or classification (discrete $\hat{y}$) to me.